# Local Lorentz Reference Frame

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, inertial-frames

What is a local Lorentz reference frame? How exactly does it differ from an inertial reference frame or a locally inertial reference frame? Are there synonyms of this expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lorentz frame and inertial frame are synonymous.

When you move from special to general relativity it is not always possible to find a coordinate system$^1$ such that [the metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor_(general_relativity)) is the Minkowski metric at all points. You can however find *local* inertial coordinate systems such that the metric is Minkowski at a *point*, these are the "*local* inertial frames" and they correspond to an observer free-falling in the gravitational field.

In special relativity a local inertial frame is a global inertial frame.

$^1$ Note the use of "coordinate system" rather than "frame". In special relativity we usually (although we don't *have* to) deal with special coordinate systems that correspond to inertial obervers. In general relativity this restriction is lifted and any admissible coordinate system (cylindrical, polar etc.) is fair game.

Comment: Thanks so much!